# О слове "воспользует"

Tags: лексика

Существует ли в русском языке слово "воспользовать"? В переходном значении: воспользует имущество, воспользует право.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, существует только *возвратная* форма глагола с такой приставкой (**воспользоваться**), которой соответствует *непереходный* вид. Общая особенность возвратных глаголов - внутренняя замкнутость действия (косвенный характер его отношения к объекту воздействия - отсюда непереходность), во многих случаях - связанность его с *интересами* производителя действия (в частностях - *направленность на себя*):

> Возвратность.
>
> http://rusgram.ru/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

В случае глагола **воспользоваться** "косвенность" воздействия на объект выражается в *частичном* использовании его свойств или временно возникших (в связи с объектом воздействия) обстоятельств: воспользоваться можно не только самим предметом или его отдельными свойствами, а и его текущим состоянием. Столь расширенными смысловыми особенностями глагол **воспользоваться** и отличается от родственного ему по смыслу *переходного* глагола **использовать**.

Answer (score 1):

Ведь всё так просто, что проще некуда: открыть словари и посмотреть. Да ещё и в "переходном значении". Что такое переходное значение?!

Comment: В значении переходного глагола, т. е. такого, который соотносится с существительным в винительном падеже.